# Error de sintaxis al actualizar datos en MySQL

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Estoy intentado actualizar datos de un usuario en mysql. Alguien puede identificarme el motivo por el cual me sale el siguiente error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'dip=133.421, nombre=Antonio, apellidos=Bielo Lopez WHERE id=1' at line 1`

Este es mi query:

```
$insertar="UPDATE usuarios SET  dip='".$dip0."', nombre='".$nombre0."', apellidos='".$apellidos0."', sexo='".$genero0."', telefono='".$telefono0."', correo='".$correo0."', username='".$username0."' WHERE id='".$id0."'";
```

Si necesitan más información para identificar el problema, díganme, porfavor.

Comment: En principio parece valida. Puedes ponernos la estructura de tabla. PD: Ojo, esa sentencia es muy vulnerable a inyeccion SQL, usa mejor consultas preparadas.

Comment: Prueba a quitar las comillas simples para la id: `"UPDATE usuarios SET dip='".$dip0."', nombre='".$nombre0."', apellidos='".$apellidos0."', sexo='".$genero0."', telefono='".$telefono0."', correo='".$correo0."', username='".$username0."' WHERE id=".$id0;`

Comment: ¿podrías mostrar un volcado de la variable $insertar? y ya de paso ejecutarla directamente en la base de datos a ver si el error se mantiene.

Answer (score 2):

Probablemente estés utilizando las comillas en campos numéricos (int, float, etc), si es así en dichos campos quita las comillas simples.

Comment: Era algo que ver con las comillas, tenía alguna de más. explico en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Tenía alguna comilla de más en algunas variables:

No

```
$nombre0=$_POST["nombre0'"];
```

Sí

```
$nombre0=$_POST["nombre0"];
```

supongo que fue el problema. no sé. borré todo mi código y volví a comenzar de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Se que este tema tiene tiempo, pero hoy he tenido el mismo problema y lo he resuelto usando el método $_POST en vez del $_GET, y ha actualizado la tabla, en el curso que estoy haciendo el instructor utiliza el metodo $_GET.

query($sql);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }
?>

este es mi codigo para actualizar la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

El error es que ni nombre ni apellidos tiene comillas.

Ciertamente la query que muestras pone comillas en los campos, pero algo haces con los datos porque el error es claro:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'dip=133.421, nombre=**Antonio**, apellidos=**Bielo Lopez** WHERE id=1'
>   at line 1

(edito)

Por si hay dudas, en caso de no poner comillas el error es de sintaxis no de `Unknow colum` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y con comillas :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fijate que en su query si los tiene.

Comment: los tendrá, pero me fío de lo que veo y no veo que se ejecute ese query ;)

Comment: Ver ves ambas cosas. Si no tuviera comillas el error seria 'Unknow colum Antonio'

Comment: Me reitero en lo dicho, al menos, en mi configuración actual MariaDB 10.0.34 tal como muestra la imagen que añadí a la respuesta

Comment: Y yo me reitero en que no es eso, el error no da en el mismo sitio, a ti te apunta al segundo apellido y a el al dip.

Comment: Parece correcto eso que dices.

Comment: Eh!! ese error no corresponde a esa query!! En el error después del apellido va el WHERE y en el texto de la consulta están los demás campos en medio ¿no?

Comment: Si, en eso no me habia fijado.  ¿ @TonyBielo puedes explicar eso?